# Django + NGINX 404 Not Found

Tags: django, nginx, django-staticfiles

Whenever I run server using `gunicorn --bind` command, all static files load without any error.
but when I try to access my domain It gives 404 error.

## Django

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/html/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

## Nginx

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server{
        root /var/www/html;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name 65.1.254.234;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/Application_Code/app.sock;
        }
        location /static {
                autoindex on;
                alias /var/www/html;
        }
}
```

Is there any problem happening due to .env file?

Comment: Why the `try_files` line? I don't think you need it. Put the `/static` location before the proxy for your app

Comment: Thanx for replying, will try this and will revert back to you.

Comment: `alias /var/www/html` -> `root /var/www/html` or `alias /var/www/html/static`